# Select rows from a table where row in another table with multiple condition

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables **App**, **concept** and **app_to_concept**

**App table**

```
app_id |    app_name

=================

1      |    foo
2      |    bar
3      |    foobar
4      |    barfoo
```

**concept table**

```
concept_id    |    concept_name
=========================
1              |    english
2              |    math
3              |    science
4              |    Fun
```

**app_to_concept table**

```
concept_id    |    app_id
=========================
1              |    1
2              |    1
3              |    2
4              |    3
2              |    2
2              |    4
```

I want to get all `app list` which have concept `english` and `math` (For example)

How can I achieve this?

### Edit

Let me be more specific

I have some checkbox having value with concepts. When i checked checkbox it returns apps detail related to checked concept. Now my case is explaining with example

if i checked `english` and `math` concept checkbox then it will show app detail having concept `english` **or** `math` and similarly for `science` and `fun`.
Now when i checked `english`,`math` and `science` then result should show app detail having `english` **or** `math` **and** `science`. Means app having

`english` and `science`

`math` and `science`

Answer (score 0):

Basic `JOIN` will do.

```
select a.app_name
from app_to_concept ac 
    INNER JOIN app_table a ON ac.app_id = a.app_id
    INNER JOIN concept_table c ON ac.concept_id = c.concept_id
WHERE c.concept_name IN ('english', 'math');
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: when i check `english` and `math` concept then it should give me `foo` because `foo` has both concept